# h:outputText is not escaping HTML entities

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, html-escape

I am having an issue where '<' is NOT escaped by outputText in JSF.

I am running Tomcat 7.0.40 with JSF 2.0, and have the following declarations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:view contentType="text/html" encoding="UTF-8">
```

This line breaks the HTML because the '<' is NOT escaped:

```
<h:outputText value="Some < text from the database"/>
```

The output shows "Some" and then the HTML is broken because of the un-escaped '<'

The '<' is correct in the database, and it also renders correctly in the form text box:

```
 <p:inputText value="#{db_data}" ... />
```

My web.xml file contains:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

A bit of my POM...

```
 <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.12</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <!-- Or 1.5-SNAPSHOT -->
    </dependency>
```

Of course, other HTML entities are also NOT being escaped: &, >, etc.

Regardless if I use `#{output}`, `<h:outputText value="#{output}"/>`, or `<h:outputText value="#{output}" escape="true"/>`, the output is NOT escaped...

Comment: Are you using this specific example or are you using a property String that holds a `<`?

Comment: I am retrieving a String from the database (into a backing bean String field) that contains an unencoded '<' in it...

Comment: I have also been trying with a hard-coded string directly in the XHTML to make sure it's not a DB driver issue.

Comment: Whatever the database is returning, the JSF control should escape it correctly so that should not be the issue.

Comment: I guess you might have to set `escape=true` in `<h:outputText>` to escape XML characters

Comment: Never seen this. This is definitely not a configuration setting. Which JSF impl/version are you using? Any chance that you've copypasted/modified some JSF impl specific source codes in your project?

Comment: I'm using jsf-impl 2.1.12. I added my POM settings above...

Comment: According Mojarra issue database, there was indeed a bug like that in 2.1.12. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by upgrading to jsf-impl 2.1.26.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in Mojarra 2.1.12 which is reported as [issue 2503](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2503) and fixed in 2.1.13.

So, if you upgrade to at least Mojarra 2.1.13, then this peculiar problem should disappear.